# UiAutomator Detect Tablet vs Phone

Tags: android-uiautomator

Is there a way using Android's uiautomator to detect whether the device being tested upon is a phone or a tablet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. You can get the width and height of the device using the function calls getUiDevice().getDisplayWidth() and getUiDevice().getDisplayHeight(). You can use ADB to get the pixel density: getprop ro.sf.lcd_density. Then using the formula px = dp * (dpi / 160) you can generate the formula dp = px / (dpi / 160). Lastly, screen sizes according to Android are specified as follows: small - 426dp x 320dp, normal - 470dp x 320dp, large - 640dp x 480dp, and xlarge - 960dp x 720dp where large and xlarge screen sizes are tablets :). Enjoy!

```
public boolean isTablet() throws Exception {
    double widthpx = getUiDevice().getDisplayWidth();
    double heightpx = getUiDevice().getDisplayHeight();

    Runtime runtime =  Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process =  runtime.exec("getprop ro.sf.lcd_density");

    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    double dpi = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());

    double widthdp = widthpx / (dpi / 160);
    double heightdp = heightpx / (dpi / 160);

    return (widthdp >= 640 && heightdp >= 480);
}
```